# What should I be looking for in a (beginner's) running shoe?

Tags: running, running-shoes

Shops being closed presents a bit of a problem...

I'm new to running, currently doing C25K and loving it so far. But I can already tell my shoes are not good for me. I'd like to buy a good value all-round pair to see me through the next 6 months.

Currently I wear [this miscellaneous pair of Nikes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xis2d.jpg) that I've had for a few years in a cupboard. However, my ankles don't feel very supported and I fear rolling over on one.

Unfortunately I have one flat foot (left), whereas my right foot has a normal arch. The left foot feels vulnerable to rolling over on in particular because the lack of an arch is causing my ankle to tilt inwards - [here are some NSFL photos of my feet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b82s9.jpg).

In terms of strike, I have tried heel striking in my current shoes and it gave me really bad ankle/calf pain. Mid-sole striking is so far working the best for me. At my current pace, forefoot striking feels odd. So mid-sole seems like a compromise technique.

As for terrain, I run on concrete, grass, cycle/walking paths through woods, nothing untoward. I don't do trail running or track running.

I am fully aware that the best way to choose a shoe is to go to a running shop and do proper gait analysis etc. This is not currently possible in the UK. Therefore all I'm wanting to do is make *an informed decision*.

What aspects of a running shoe can objectively address these points, if it's possible to say so?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I have high arches so I in a way know what you're going through.. I'd suggest going to a podiatrist and getting a custom made set of orthotics for your feet that you can slip in your running shoes. Feet are very unique, especially if you only have one flat foot, so relying on  running shoes with an insert designed for you is going to be difficult. You just slip out the old inserts and put your customized versions(each foot will be different) in your running shoes. Your feet will eventually get worse or you will get plantar fasciitis, etc if you keep running with a flat foot and no orthotics.

After you get the orthotics, Nike has the pegusus zoom shoes which seem to be great and feel great, and they will also be the longest lasting. They have versions with Flyknit which is nice if you want more breathability and lightweight shoes. They also have the free RN shoes that are designed to make it feel like your not wearing shoes, and the sole mimicks your feet with bumps in different areas so it feels like your barefoot walking which feels amazing. You can also get special shoes designed for sprinting and short runs, HIIT, etc just look on their website. It tells you what each shoe can do and how it's designed for it. If you're not competing, you don't need to see a shoe specialist. Just get what feels best, if you just enjoy running for fun, the free RN shoes are great. I'd avoid Flyknit or lightweight shoes if you're interested in long term durability however. Nikes shoes have a new "release" each year so you can get last year's model or the latest and greatest

Keep in mind if you get orthotics that not all shoes have removable inserts.